# Config controller dependency with Request data using AutoFac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

How can i config container at startup, when RequestContext is not available yet?
I need to pass a parameter to dependency from request, how can i achieve that?
I need something like below.

```
builder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IService>()
           .WithParameters(new[]
           {
                new NamedParameter("param", Request.Host)
           })
.InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: You should not inject runtime values into your application components, as explained [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/injecting-configured-parameters.html

This things need to be configured with providers.